# Cannot import name error in Django split models

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-module, django-serializer

I have split the Django models into multiple model files following the follow file tree structure,

```
+-api(app)-+
           +-__init__.py
           +-models -+
                     |
                     +-__init__.py
                     +-model1.py
                     +-model2.py
                     +-model3.py
           +-serializers-+
                     |
                     +-__init__.py
                     +- model1_serializer.py
           +-views
           +-apps.py
               ...
```

my `__init__.py` in models looks like,

```
from .model1 import *
from .model2 import *
```

and serializer `__init__.py` files look like this,

```
from .model1_serializer import MBTITypeSerializer
```

I have splitter views files and serializer files. When I try to import models some of them imports without any problem, but some imports not working. I have observed if I change the import order in `__init__.py` file the working imports change. This is how I tried to import  models,

in `serializers`

```
from api.models import MBTIType
...
```

Here is the error trace,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\ \implementation\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\api\models\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .model1 import *
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\api\models\model1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .model2 import Model2
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\api\models\model2.py", line 5, in <module>
    from api.serializers import serilizer1
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\api\serializers\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .model1_serializer import Model1Serializer
  File "D:\\implementation\backend\api\serializers\model1_serializer.py", line 2, in <module>
    from api.models import Model1
ImportError: cannot import name 'Model1' from 'api.models' (D:\\implementation\backend\api\models\__init__.py)
```

Hoping any guidance to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your `model2.py`, you have there on line 5 `from api.serializers import serilizer1`

But you don't need to have `serializer1` in models.

Comment: Yeah, I need a serializer in the model because I have to serialize `model1` in `model2` property. Models are related.

Comment: You were right issue was due to that reason